# How to create a symbol that is alike for indices around empty {}?

Tags: symbols

How can I create the symbol shown below so that it be insertable as letter into text in LaTeX?

[image]

I found it in a book and I tried to reverse engineer it, but I failed:

```
% does not compile {}[\bf{п}]^(\bf{п}){}[\bf{м}]^(\bf{у})
% does not compile {}^{\bf{п}}_{\bf{п}}\mathbf{C}^{\bf{м}}_{\bf{у}}
```

Comment: Something like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/gTwkA.png)?

Comment: Are any of the elements fixed/dynamic or does the "symbol" always the way you present it in your post? Also, when you mention "indices", are you referring to the "top part" as being a superscript and the "bottom part" as being a subscript?

Comment: This is a good opportunity for `stackengine` probably.

Comment: Or a simple use of `\shortstack{<top>\\<bottom>}`....  (Which is not to say that `stackengine` is pretty awesome.)

Comment: What is the purpose of the dot(s) in the image at the right side? Where is the base line of the symbol? What is its height?

Answer (score 2):

Some low level programming can help:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\pmpu}{%
  \leavevmode\vbox{
    \check@mathfonts %% we want to know what's the subsubscript size
    \fontencoding{T2A}\fontsize{\ssf@size}{0}\selectfont
    \offinterlineskip
    \lineskip=0pt
    \ialign{%
      &\hfil##\hfil\cr
      \CYRP&\CYRM\cr
      \noalign{\vskip.1ex}
      \CYRP&\CYRU\cr
    }%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Text around \pmpu\ and other text

\bigskip

{\Large Text around \pmpu\ and other text}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image: whatsis]

Change scale factor to change font size.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphics}

\newcommand{\whatsis}[1]% scale factor - 0.4 is normalsize
{\scalebox{#1}{\normalsize\raisebox{8pt}{$\Pi$M }\hspace{-20pt}%
{$\Pi$\hspace{1pt}\raisebox{1.65pt}{\large y.}}}}%

\begin{document}
\huge text \whatsis{0.8} text
\end{document}
```

Comment: ...that's why it's better to use font-related measurements like `ex` and `em`.

Comment: The \large y will still remain \large.

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust the `.15ex` if you wish to change the distance between the stacked lines.  In this MWE, the symbol is made to fit to `1.95ex` in vertical extent, which can also be adjusted.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian,english]{babel}
\usepackage{scalerel,tabstackengine,graphicx}
\def\mysym{\foreignlanguage{russian}{%
  \setstackgap{S}{.15ex}\scaleto{$\tabbedShortstack{п&м\\п&у}$}{1.95ex}}}
\def\test{a\mysym b}
\begin{document}
{\Large\test}\par\test\par{\footnotesize\test}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And if one prefers the symbol in bold, as the OP's graphic might indicate, a one-word change to the MWE accomplishes that:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian,english]{babel}
\usepackage{scalerel,tabstackengine,graphicx}
\def\mysym{\foreignlanguage{russian}{%
  \setstackgap{S}{.15ex}\scaleto{$\bfseries\tabbedShortstack{п&м\\п&у}$}{1.95ex}}}
\def\test{a\mysym b}
\begin{document}
{\Large\test}\par\test\par{\footnotesize\test}
\end{document}
```

[image]